# How to join separate table data column in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, joincolumn

Is there any possible variant to insert data from another table into Hibernate entity. 
For example we have the following DB-model:

```
ItemTable:
ITEM_ID NUMBER not null,
ITEM_NAME VARCHAR2,
I_OBJECT_ID NUMBER;

ObjectTable:
OBJECT_ID NUMBER not null,
OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2;
```

And the following java-code:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "ITEMTABLE")
public class ItemDTO {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ITEM_ID")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "ITEM_NAME")
   private String itemName;

   @Column(name = "I_OBJECT_ID")
   protected long objectId;

   **//TODO: here we need OBJECT_NAME column form ObjectTable**
   private String objectName;

}
```

So we need just one column not the whole ObjectTable entity for **objectName** prop.

I've tried construction like:

```
@JoinTable(name = "OBJECTTABLE", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID", referencedColumnName = "I_OBJECT_ID") })
@Column(name = "OBJECT_NAME")
```

But it fails with:

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "ITEMDTO0_"."OBJECT_NAME": invalid identifier
```

Every example of **@JoinTable** or **@JoinColumn** assume that I need to include another entity as a prop which will be redundant and slow.

Can this be solved in any way?

**P.S.** just two cents about why I do not want include second entity into first one, is because I want my JpaRepository will allow me to sort/filter directly over joined column.

Please advise.

Comment: You could consider mapping the property through a SecondaryTable

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling it doesn't work, see my comment under **zforgo**'s answer

Comment: Creating entities for your DTO's is a bit hacky. Consider using Blaze-Persistence Entity Views for creating your DTO's. Its considerable the best DTO projection library for JPA out there: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.3/entity-view/manual/en_US/

Comment: It comes with a Spring Data integration FWIW

Answer (score 1):

Using `@SecondaryTable` annotation it's easy to map multiple tables to the same entity. More precisely JPA joins the primary table with the secondary table and populates the fields.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ItemTable")
@SecondaryTable(name = "ObjectTable", pkJoinColumns = 
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID", referencedColumnName="I_OBJECT_ID")
)
public class ItemDTO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ITEM_ID")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "ITEM_NAME")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "OBJECT_NAME", table = "ObjectTable")
    private String objectName;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ObjectTable")
public class ObjectsEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "OBJECT_ID")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "OBJECT_NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

BTW: In the question the names of the columns and tables are different in the data model and the `@Table` and `@Column` annotations. It should be consolidated.

Comment: I've tried this solution and here what I've got: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: SecondaryTable JoinColumn cannot reference a non primary key.